# using regex to remove the opening brackets of JSON data coldfusion

Tags: regex, json, coldfusion

I am working with JSON data and response is coming very good

```
[
    {
        "s": "1",
        "sent": "September, 11 2014 18:19:10 -0400",
        "f": "user1",
        "m": "the place",
        "fr": "user2"
    },
    {
        "s": "1",
        "sent": "September, 11 2014 18:19:19 -0400",
        "f": "user2",
        "m": "that once decided",
        "fr": "user1"
    },
    {
        "s": "1",
        "sent": "September, 11 2014 18:19:23 -0400",
        "f": "user1",
        "m": "on your side",
        "fr": "user2"
    },
    {
        "s": "1",
        "sent": "September, 11 2014 18:19:43 -0400",
        "f": "user2",
        "m": "actually i moved the text",
        "fr": "user1"
    },
    {
        "s": "1",
        "sent": "September, 11 2014 18:20:06 -0400",
        "f": "user2",
        "m": "nothing specific",
        "fr": "user1"
    }
]
```

I would like to remove the ending and starting `[]` from the JSON, currently I have to write two `Replace` to do it, but it works sometimes and sometimes it does not. What could be relevant `regex` to sort out this issue. please guide

regards

Comment: What you want to do with data? It is array of structures and easily, very easily manipulative with CF.

Comment: i just wanna to remove the opening and closing brackets, that is the requirement as of now and i am facing issue solving it. i had a working with somewhat replace but that is not consistant

Comment: Replace should work without doing anything fancy. Are you specifying any position to start looking for? Because it is possible that json string have leading/trailing blanks with them.

Comment: Pretty sure that when you remove the `[` and `]`, it is no longer valid JSON. So...why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with one `replace` using a [regex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a38f-7ffb.html) with an alternation (`|`) `^\s*\[|]\s*$`. That says: Match any series of whitespace followed by `[` from the beginning of the string (`^\s*\[`), or match `]` followed by any series of whitespace at the end of the string (`[\s*$`) with nothing. [Gratuitous online explanation of the regex](http://regex101.com/r/jZ1lU9/1). Use that with [`REReplace`](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_27.html) (for instance) with `scope` set to `all` and a blank string as the replacement.

Comment: is it with coldfusion prospective, like can i use it with `Rematch`

Comment: @samsu: Sorry, I had JavaScript in my head for some reason. Having looked at the (now linked) regex page for ColdFusion, yes, that regex works in its variant as well, so you can use `REReplace` to do it.